# Al seleccionar el agregar en mi modal se mande el id a la caja de texto de mi formulario

Tags: javascript, php

Aquí está mi lista de mi modal:

[image: Captura de pantalla del código PHP y JavaScript]

Esta es mi interfaz:

[image: Captura de pantalla de la página del navegador mostrando la ventana modal]

¿Cómo podría hacer para que cuando seleccione el agregar en mi modal ese id lo mande a mi caja de texto de mi formulario?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código copiando y pegando en vez de con capturas de pantalla?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Nos vendría muy bien tener tu código para poder reproducir tu problema. Con capturas de pantalla nos dificultas mucho poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo proporcionando como parámetro el contenido de `$result['id_sub']` como parámetro de la llamada a la función.

Puedes hacerlo en PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
<tbody>
<?php while (Sresult = mysqli_fetch_array($query)): ?>
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td id="id_sub<?= htmlspecialchars($result['id_sub']) ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($result['id_sub']) ?>
        </td>
        <td id="nombre_sub<?= htmlspecialchars($result['nombre sub']) ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($result['nombre sub']) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="add(<?= htmlspecialchars($result['id_sub']) ?>);">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

Pero luego necesitarás modificar tu código JavaScript de la siguiente manera:

```
function add(id) {
  /* Ocultamos la ventana modal */
  $('#tu_modal').modal('hide');
  /* Asignamos al campo del formulario con id "id_sub" el valor proporcionado */
  id_sub.value = id;
}
```

NOTA: Por favor, usa [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) para enviar datos al navegador para evitar que el diseño de tu página se rompa o que sea vulnerable a ataques [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Ejemplo:

```js
function add(id) {
  /* Ocultamos la ventana modal */
  $('#tu_modal').modal('hide');
  /* Asignamos al campo del formulario con id "id_sub" el valor proporcionado */
  id_sub.value = id;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_sub" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tu_modal">Agregar nuevo</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="tu_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tu_modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button onclick="add(1)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Agregar 1</button>
        <button onclick="add(2)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Agregar 2</button>
        <button onclick="add(3)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Agregar 3</button>
        <button onclick="add(4)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Agregar 4</button>
        <button onclick="add(5)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Agregar 5</button>
        <button onclick="add(6)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Agregar 6</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con Javascript. Se puede hacer de varias maneras, pero lo más básico sería llamar a una función dentro del `button` que mande como parámetro el valor del `id` al campo del formulario que desees. Algo así (fragmento)

```
onclick="add('1');" // 1 es un ejemplo del valor
```

Y la posible función, donde `destino` es el `id` del input donde debe guardarse el valor (cambiar según corresponda)

```
function add(id) {
  document.getElementById("destino").value = id;
}
```

Debes también quitar el `href` del `button` para que no funcione como un link.